# MYSQL Trigger concat

Tags: mysql, triggers, concatenation

I am currently facing an issue in concatenating "NEW" Keyword with column names using concat function..

```
 SET @values =
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('.','new', table1.col) SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM tbale1, table2, table3, table4
WHERE table3.table3_id = '001' 
AND table3.id = table4.table3_id 
AND table4.col = table2.col 
AND table1.id = table2.table1_id 
ORDER BY table2.col);
```

ON execution, instead of replacing the values for NEW keyword(last inserted records/values) it just returns as NEW.col1,NEW.col2,NEW.col3 instead of their assigned values.please help me out with this..

desired output is SELECT @var ='aa','bb','cc','ccc'; 
        But current output is SELECT @var = NEW.col1,NEW.col2,NEW.col3,NEW.col4;

Comment: Your question is quite unclear and your code is actually worse.  The actual code being run (or a reasonable simplification), sample data, and desired results should help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have edited the question now with expected output and current output...pls help me..

Comment: Your query returns a syntax error.

Comment: the actual query is          SET @values =
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('.','new', table1.col) SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM tbale1, table2, table3, table4, table4 
WHERE table3.table3_id = '001' 
AND table3.id = table4.table3_id 
AND table3.id = table4.table3_id 
AND table4.col = table2.col 
AND table4.col = table2.col
AND table1.id = table2.table1_id 
ORDER BY table2.col);                          please help me..

Comment: I have edited the question now pls check. guys...

Comment: ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'table4'

Comment: If you are trying to "evaluate" strings stored in columns as column names, then you need dynamic SQL.  Beyond that, it is unclear what you are really trying to do.